# how to change direction of tabular command in xepersian (ltr to ltr)

Tags: tables, tabularx, xepersian

**Problem Definition:**

Because of using `xepersian` package, my defualt text direction is rtl (Right-to-Left). I have created a table using the following piece of code:

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|cc|cc|}
        \hline
    $G_{mother}$ & $G_{father}$ & $P(G_{child} = l | G_{mother}, G_{father})$ & $P(G_{child} = r | G_{mother}, G_{father})$
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Which displays the table like:

[image: tabular]

**Question:** 
How to change direction of tabular (ltr to ltr)? More precisely, I mean the top left cell would be $G_{mother}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For long LTR texts use `\begin{latin} ... \end{latin}`. Optionally, you can call `relsize` so your table does not invade the right margin. Here's an example:

```
%!TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Noto Naskh Arabic}
\setlatintextfont{Noto Naskh Arabic}
\begin{document}
%Copied from https://ganjoor.net/moulavi/
%RTL by default
\noindent
مولانا جلال‌الدین محمد بلخی مشهور به مولوی شاعر بزرگ قرن هفتم هجری قمری است. وی در سال ۶۰۴ هجری قمری در بلخ زاده شد. پدر وی بهاءالدین که از علما و صوفیان بزرگ زمان خود بود به سبب رنجشی که بین او و سلطان محمد خوارزمشاه پدید آمده بود از بلخ بیرون آمد و بعد از مدتی سیر و سیاحت به قونیه رفت. مولانا بعد از فوت پدر تحت تعلیمات برهان‌الدین محقق ترمذی قرار گرفت. ملاقات وی با شمس تبریزی در سال ۶۴۲ هجری قمری انقلابی در وی پدید آورد که موجب ترک مسند تدریس و فتوای وی شد و به مراقبت نفس و تذهیب باطن پرداخت. وی در سال ۶۷۲ هجری قمری در قونیه وفات یافت. از آثار او می‌توان به مثنوی، دیوان غزلیات یا کلیات شمس، رباعیات، مکتوبات، فیه مافیه و مجالس سبعه اشاره کرد.
%Switch to LTR
\begin{latin}
\bgroup\smaller 
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|cc|cc|}
        \hline
        $G_{mother}$ & $G_{father}$ & $P(G_{child} = l | G_{mother}, G_{father})$ & $P(G_{child} = r | G_{mother}, G_{father})$ \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\egroup
\end{latin}
\end{document}
```

[image]